# OpenXml Spreadsheet Output gives "General Error" opening in OpenOffice when containing a large number of rows

Tags: c#, excel, runtime-error, openxml, openoffice-calc

Spreadsheet output of OpenXML works in Excel (and Google Docs) but throws a runtime error in OpenOffice 4.x...

Specific error is

> General Error.
>
> General input/output error.

with no further explanation. It, in practice, has only occurred for me if there were greater than 40 rows for the spreadsheet; however, there did not seems to be a specific number of rows that caused the issue.

*I have already created a workaround for the issue.* This post is just to share my horrible, horrible solution for those that just need something.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Does the same error occur using a recent version of LibreOffice?  Also, it would be a good idea to post a link to the OpenXML MSDN examples to show how the problematic file was created, so that the problem is reproducible.  One more thing: You can post an answer to your own question.  So it would be better to move everything starting from "my horrible, horrible solution" to an answer instead of leaving it in the question.

Comment: I haven't had opportunity to check it out in LibreOffice, but I have a separate machine available in which I could do so. As for the generator, problematic file, I will see if I can make one: the original is part of a work project that cannot be disclosed. As for your suggestion, I may take it once I produce the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the cause might be in the Zip headers or part of the zip entries themselves and that their is either a bug in the library that writes the Zip output for the System.IO.Packaging namespace (which I assume that OpenXML uses) or that OpenOffice has a very simple zip reader. Maybe something with the central directory file offsets versus the compressed file size, but I did not bother to check as I had limited time.

I may investigate further one day, or if anyone knows a quick solution, then do let me know. The files are written using the examples found on MSDN and they do open correctly in Excel.

In the meantime, if anyone needs a band-aid to the issue, I am posting my quick fix here since I was unable to find one myself. It expects a byte array (perhaps dumped from MemorySteam or read a FileStream). It outputs another byte array.

Someone clever could have it accept a Stream, seek to 0 relative to Beginning, and then read from there, perhaps writing directly to another passed in stream. That would be an exercise to the reader, unless someone happens to post a response that does the same.

*If anyone does have a better solution, I would not mind knowing.*

Uses .NET 4.5

References System.IO.Compression

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace redmasq {
   public static class ExcelFileFixExample {
        public static byte[] XLSXOpenOfficePackageFix(byte[] fileData) {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData, false)) {
                using (ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(ms)) {
                    using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream()) {
                        using (ZipArchive za2 = new ZipArchive(ms2, ZipArchiveMode.Create)) {
                            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in za.Entries) {
                                ZipArchiveEntry zae = za2.CreateEntry(entry.FullName, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                                using (Stream src = entry.Open()) {
                                    using (Stream dest = zae.Open()) {
                                        src.CopyTo(dest);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return ms2.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```